# Linux command prompt reading and passing date to java -D option

Tags: java, hadoop

I am working on a Map Reduce job using hadoop, in which the command to run the job will look like below

```
jar path_to_jar.jar -Dmongo.input.query=' {"created_at":"2013-06-13"}' path_to_config_class
```

this works fine when I manually pass the created at date, but how should I make it dynamic, say I want to add this in a cron job which runs one day once, and at time of running I need to take the 
current date of the system and pass.

I found I can use `date +"%Y-%m-%d"` to get `2013-06-13` (current date) in Linux prompt, but how do I pass it with -D option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `printf` command:

```
# Generate query
QUERY=$(printf ' {"created_at":"%s"}' $(date +%Y-%m-%d))
# Use it as an argument
jar path_to_jar.jar -Dmongo.input.query="$QUERY" etc etc
```

Comment: Actually the output of `QUERY=$(printf ' {"created_at":"%s"}' $(date +%Y-%m-%d))` is `{"created_at":"2013-06-13"}`.

But the desired output is `'{"created_at":"2013-06-13"}'`, I tried to add a single quote in printf statement with escape sequence, but its not working..

Comment: By "desired output", do you mean this is what your jar expects?

Comment: I can able to get the desired output when calling the `echo $QUERY`, but facing some issue like `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided JSON String is not representable/parseable as a DBObject.` Thanks for suggesting this method.

Comment: Uh, OK, what is the call? What are its valid inputs? Are you sure about the surrounding single quotes?

Comment: Yes.. I am sure.. 
when I give it as shown in the question, it works (hardcoded)

Comment: OK, look carefully: what you pass _to the shell_ is `-Dmongo.input.query=' {"created_at":"2013-06-13"}'`; what the argument _really is_ is `-Dmongo.input.query= {"created_at":"2013-06-13"}`! Try and type `'ls'` at the command line, you'll see that it works. So does `"l"'s'` (yes, try it!). Therefore my original answer was correct.

Comment: yes. your answer is correct and shows required output when running..
I just need to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(date +%Y-%m-%d) //execute
```

so you command in terminal window looks like

```
jar path_to_jar.jar -Dmongo.input.query=' {"created_at":"'$(date +%Y-%m-%d)'"}' path_to_config_class
```